# already faced said reprisal and came back for more

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

It seems to me that "came back for more" refers to "already faced said reprisal and came back for more (reprisal)". But then the grammar is inconsistent:  The present perfect (have already faced said reprisal) means facing reprisal has continued to the present time; so if you have the courage to face more, you have to use the present tense (come back for more) rather than the past tense (came back for more).

What does "came back for more" mean then?

> The Daily Wire tweeted:
>
> Meet the few, the proud, the openly conservative artists willing to embrace smaller government without fear of reprisal.
>
> Or, they’ve **already faced said reprisal and came back for more**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The present perfect (have already faced said reprisal) means facing reprisal has continued to the present time

That's not necessarily the case - Present Perfect has numerous uses, and one of them is to talk about "life experience" - situations which have happened at some point in the past, but it's not important *when* they happened, only that they *have* happened as opposed to you having never experienced them:

> I've written a few books. *(I have experience with writing books in general, it doesn't matter when I did it)*

So in this case, the Present Perfect is very likely used in that sense - it refers to reprisal which has happened in the past, but the important part isn't what it was or when it happened, just the fact that those conservative artists have experienced it at some point.

And to *come back for more* means not just to have the courage to face - in this case - reprisal, but to actively do something to put yourself in a situation where you would be facing it. This part being in Simple Past puts more emphasis on the specific actions the artist did to *come back for more* reprisal, rather than them having general experience with said *coming back*. Compare:

> I **have read** this book several times *(Present Perfect - at some points, doesn't matter when, just that I'm very familiar with the book)*, but I **decided** to read it again *(Simple Past - referring to a specific instance of me making that decision)*.

Comment: Apparently "I decided to read it" - the decision was made in the past, so I wonder why not use Past Perfect, rather than Present Perfect to describe the fact that before this decision you had already read it several times?      Past Perfect appears to make the grammar consistent in the OP situation.  Grammar Book has this: "The past perfect refers to a time earlier than before now. It is used to make it clear that one event happened before another in the past. " It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @NewPlanet Past Perfect seems rather redundant here - the context and ordering of the sentence make it clear that the reading/facing reprisal came somewhere before coming back/deciding to read. It also doesn't let you use Simple Past/Present Perfect to distinguish between describing a sequence of events and an event in context, which can be meaningful. (cont.)

Comment: @NewPlanet For example, if the context of the conversation is "what you were doing yesterday", *I **have read**... but I **decided**...* implies that only the decision was made yesterday, and the fact that you've read the book already is provided for context. *I **read**... but I **decided**...* implies that you read the book multiple times that day, then decided to read it again.

Answer (score 0):

*[They] have already faced said reprisal* does **not** mean that the reprisals are continuing at the present time; that would be *are already facing.* However, I would expect the sentence to continue... *and [have] come back for more.*

I don't think the tenses go together very well, but the sentence can be read as *They have faced reprisals [in the past] and they came back for more.*